# Netbeans Java Enterprise Web Application: cannot find symbol class Table

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, enterprise

so I followed this tutorial [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zW27Y2boCo) ([source](http://www.mediafire.com/download/0xf3zqp5s10a6o7/CRUDWebApplication.zip))
to create a Java Enterprise Web Application and have ran into a problem. As this is pretty much the first time working with stuff like this for me I am clueless regarding how to solve this.

When trying to run the project I get an error saying "The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details." After some time trying to find out what was wrong I figured it is most likely the error I have in my "Student.java"-class. It says  "cannot find symbol classTable. Create Subclass Create Test Class". What may be the problem here? I'm not sure what code would be relevant as I am a complete beginner to this, but all my files are exact copies of the source code-wise. Here is Student.java:

```
package com.joseph.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
*
* @author Joseph
*/
@Entity
@Table
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="Student.getAll",query="SELECT e FROM     Student e")})
public class Student implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private int studentId;
@Column
private String firstname;
@Column
private String lastname;
@Column
private int yearLevel;

public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public int getYearLevel() {
    return yearLevel;
}

public void setYearLevel(int yearLevel) {
    this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
}

public Student(int studentId, String firstname, String lastname, int yearLevel) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
}

public Student(){}
}
```

Comment: The Student class looks ok, you should add the exception from `server.log` to the question...

Comment: Exception while deploying the app [CRUDWebApplication] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Error Code: 0





//Would that be it?

Comment: Yes, that's it. The message indicates that the Derby database is not running.

Comment: @unwichtich so that would be the Java DB/jdbc I guess... hmm ok thank you